# TextBox Accepting only a decimal number with two precisions (eg: ddd.dd)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a textbox which need to restrict the user for entering other than decimal number (with maximum of three digits and then a period and then maximun of two digits). Can someone suggest me Onkeypress Event for the textbox in jQuery For this requirement

Comment: Let's see what you've tried. Post your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code

```
function checkValue()
{
var num = $("#txtBox").val().split(".");
if(num[0].length<=3)
{
if(num[1].length<=2)
{
return true;
}
else
{
alert("Decimal part can not be greater than 2");
}
}
else
{
alert("Number can not be greater than 3 digits");
}
}
```

I hope this code work for you.